# Quarkus Kafka Docker Network Property

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, quarkus

Our problem is that the internal property kafka.bootstrap.servers will not be overwritten by kafka:9092.
Our container still tries to access localhost:9092.

We have set in our docker-compose.yml file for the environment of each microservice to:
environment:
- kafka.bootstrap.servers=kafka:9092
and also the same in the properties of each MS

Is there any way to overwrite this property?

edit:
important parts of our docker-compose.yml file:

```
services:  
zookeeper:
    image: strimzi/kafka:0.19.0-kafka-2.5.0
    command:
      ["sh", "-c", "bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties"]
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      LOG_DIR: /tmp/logs

  kafka:
    image: strimzi/kafka:0.19.0-kafka-2.5.0
    command:
      [
        "sh",
        "-c",
        "bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties --override listeners=$${KAFKA_LISTENERS} --override advertised.listeners=$${KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS} --override zookeeper.connect=$${KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT}",
      ]
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      LOG_DIR: "/tmp/logs"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
  authentication-service:
    build:
      context: implementation/authentication
      dockerfile: src/main/docker/Dockerfile.jvm
    environment:
      - quarkus.mongodb.connection-string=mongodb://mongodb:27017
      - KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092
    container_name: authentication-service-ase
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - kafka
```

The errors we keep getting are:

```
cart-service-ase              |
cart-service-ase              | {
cart-service-ase              |     "timestamp": "2021-06-02 12:19:48",
cart-service-ase              |     "sequence": 378,
cart-service-ase              |     "loggerClassName": "org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LogContext$LocationAwareKafkaLogger",
cart-service-ase              |     "loggerName": "org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient",
cart-service-ase              |     "level": "WARN",
cart-service-ase              |     "message": "[Consumer clientId=kafka-consumer-checkout-out, groupId=cart] Connection to node 0 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.",
cart-service-ase              |     "threadName": "vert.x-kafka-consumer-thread-1",
cart-service-ase              |     "threadId": 38,
cart-service-ase              |     "mdc": {
cart-service-ase              |     },
cart-service-ase              |     "ndc": "",
cart-service-ase              |     "hostName": "34e4de1e7647",
cart-service-ase              |     "processName": "quarkus-run.jar",
cart-service-ase              |     "processId": 1
cart-service-ase              | }
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include the (relevant parts of) `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: instead of `kafka.bootstrap.servers`, try using `KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS`

Comment: Still getting the same error saying: message: [Consumer clientId=kafka-consumer-register-out, groupId=cart] Connection to node 0 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available

Comment: Have you tried `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092`?

Comment: Where would you put that?
Because we already have it under
kafka: environment: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092` since you cannot advertise localhost to other containers in the same network. As the error says, the consumer container is trying to connect with itself, not the Kafka container.

However, you'll need to verify the override flags in the command actually set the property correctly

Comment: Thank you very much, you are my hero! It was that line: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092